# Search on binary field with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've a table that includes a binary field (says "bin") which contains 14 bytes data. I want to do a search on this field as below:

```
from row in db.users where row.bin.SequenceEqual(data) select row
```

the type of "data" variable is byte[].
but when I run "q.Count()", I encounter the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SequenceEqual[Byte]
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte], 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte])' method, 
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I retrieve the count of matches binary data?

Thanks

Comment: Do you own the data model? Can you switch the data type? With only 14 bytes of data, you could potentially make it a 21-character of base-64 encoded data that is easy to search from EF.

Comment: Yes! I've the data model. How can I treat it as base-64 encoded data? It sounds a good idea...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please write your idea as an answer, so I can mark it as correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the data model, and your binary data is small fixed-size array of bytes, you can change the SQL data type from `binary(14)` to `char(21)`, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) on the way into the database, and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) on the way out.

Switching to string will make your data searchable: simply encode your search `data` as base64 string, and use the `==` operator in the search condition.

Comment: @iRon I did not mean to imply that you'd be able to search for anything other than an exact match. OP's use of `SequenceEqual` implies that it's exactly the scenario that he's looking for.

Comment: I see your point, although all would like to leave/redo my comment, I can't undo my downvote: `You last voted on this answer 5 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`

Comment: Note that you can't search for a binary sequence on another binary sequence by converting them to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) as each byte will spread over more than one base64 character. In fact each 3 bytes will spread over 4 base64 characters. e.g. `ABC` (utf-8) will convert to: `QUJD` and `XABC` (utf-8) will convert to: `WEFCQw==`. `XABC` contains `ABC` but `WEFCQw==` doesn't contain `QUJD`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Entity Framework does not support manipulations with binary fields.

Comment: isn't any other way to do a binary search?

Comment: @Majid Well, for large binary data pulling it all down and using LINQ to Objects is probably a terrible idea...you'll want to do that at the database level in some way.

Comment: my binary data have fixed 14 bytes length. Can I do a search using classic sql commands?